# Selenium WebDriver (Ruby): flag to start Chrome maximized is lost from desired_capabilities

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capability

When I set my `desired_capabilities` for Chrome as such

```
caps = {
  "chromeOptions" => {
    "prefs" => {
      :plugins => {
        :plugins_disabled => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
      },

      :download => {
        :prompt_for_download => false,
        :directory_upgrade   => true,
        :default_directory   => ENV['files_dir']
      }
    },

    "args" => ['--start-maximized']
  }
}
```

then query `caps` with `caps['chromeOptions']['args']`, the `--start-maximized` flag is lost - this is what is returned

```
caps['chromeOptions']['args']
=> []
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: `browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps`

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the chrome capabilities first:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps.merge!(your_caps)
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: It still loses it.

Comment: What are you expecting? Are you using caps after passing it? Because yes it gets modified

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not know that it would be modified.